# Why do I get different results for the same input specified using natural language phrasing?

Tags: date-and-time, wolfram-alpha-queries, natural-language

One of the [comments](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2015/12/untangling-the-tale-of-ada-lovelace/comment-page-1/#comment-1515383) to Stephen Wolfram's blog post on Ada Lovelace, mentioned that WolframAlpha (and verified in Mathematica as well) provided slightly different results for the question of Ada's age when her father, Lord Byron, died, if the question was asked in two different ways.

Using ["death of lord byron - birth of ada lovelace"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=death%20of%20lord%20byron%20-%20birth%20of%20ada%20lovelace) gives 8 years, 4 months 22 days, while ["age of ada lovelace when Lord Byron died"](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=age%20of%20ada%20lovelace%20when%20Lord%20Byron%20died), gives 8 years, 4 months, 9 days.

On expanding the details in both answers, the resulting dates used to calculate the answer are the same. Where does this slight difference come from?

Edit: The [question](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/769797) posted in the [Wolfram Community site got no replies from the authorities, but it seems someone did correct the problem.

Comment: This site is about the Wolfram Mathematica language, not the Wolfram Alpha language. These are not really the same languages, even though they are based on the Wolfram framework. You might be better asking about the Wolfram Alpha language at the Wolfram community website, where there are many Wolfram Alpha language questions posted.

Comment: Will change question to refer to the Mathematica Language since I just verified it produces the same result.

Comment: Your question is a good one, but @Nasser's comment is motivated by the fact that, as *Mathematica* users like yourself, we do not necessarily have any special insight into the curious and arbitrary way that W|A interprets its input. And because it's a web service, the details of its functioning cannot easily be examined or tested, unlike with *Mathematica*. Hence, your chances of receiving a good answer in this very-much-unofficial forum are not high. I too would encourage you to ask at the Wolfram Community -- and by all means provide the link to your cross-post in this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is about how Wolfram|Alpha interprets its input. That it mentions _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: "Show Details" on both claims (correctly) that the date of death is April 19, but the former seems to be computing using May 1.

Comment: Natural language phrasing is now part of Mathematica, is it not? Data from the cloud is valid data to be computed on by Mathematica, I believe. If true, then I would say that it is a relevant question for this site. The reality that there might not be anyone on SE who could answer this is another problem. I _will_ post this on the Wolfram community site as well, but then I have to ask myself what Mathematica questions _are_ better posted here rather than there?

Comment: I think the issue raised about this being a Wolfram|Alpha issue, hence off-topic, might have been slightly misleading. Whether or not such questions are off-topic, it is clear that this one requires expertise outside the realm of the forum in order to provide a response. I'd say send a bug report either to support.wolfram.com or via the Wolfram|Alpha "Contact" link.

Comment: Perhaps there is a misconception here. Yes, support for natural language inputs is provided in *Mathematica*, but only by submitting that input to W|A and receiving either valid *Mathematica* code or a fully-formed output from the web service. It is rather like asking on an Android forum why Google Translate produces an incorrect result. I fully understand your frustration, but really the only people who can answer you are those familiar with W|A behavior, data sources, and even source code. These are proprietary to WRI.

Comment: This forum is totally unofficial. Therefore, WRI would probably argue that you ought to post all your questions on the Wolfram Community (which is not an official *support* forum either, by the way). But, in my opinion, this site is nicer to use and has a higher signal-to-noise ratio. I think technical questions about *Mathematica* itself are a good fit here, but really, if you see any question related to yours that is answered well, it is worth posting. We are not very particular, but we do know what we *can't* answer well, and will redirect you in those cases.